# New version of sign in form causing increased sign in failures on browser

Tags: angular, authentication, google-chrome, cross-browser, password-manager

Just deployed a new version of our sign-in form (3+ million daily users).

Our analytics show us that the new sign-in form is having 3% fewer successful sign-ins (i.e. more failures caused by an invalid username or password ).

We suspect this is related to **password managers**, but we're not sure.

Technologies: Angular version 16, JavaScript, HTML, CSS

My questions are:

- What's the best strategy for debugging this issue and finding the root cause?
- How can we know for sure if **password managers** are the root cause?

Browser success distribution is as follow:

- iOS Safari (**no difference** between old and new sign-in form versions) - **25%** of users use iOS Safari
- Windows Chrome (**3%** difference in sign-in success rates) - **40%** of users use Windows Chrome
- Windows Edge (**5%** difference in sign-in success rates) - **15%** of users use Windows Edge
- Android (**3%** difference in sign-in success rates) - **15%** of users use Android
- All other OSs/browsers (3% difference in sign-in success rates) - **5%** of users use other browsers/OSs

Comment: What did you actually change? Is there a visible/notable UI/UX difference? Did you use browser/other storage to store some parts of credentials and then forced it to clear, so users forgot their credentials and made mistakes?